# List with Custom Class and operations on List

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi, I have a class called Items.

```
class Items{
  String name;
  String picture;
  int quantity;
  int price;

  Items(@required this.name, this.picture,this.quantity,this.price);
}
```

The same class items are rendered on the screen shown in the screenshot. I have been struggling to add an   item to the cart on click of addToCart image button.Im struck at how to search the List and perform add, delete and edit operations on the list. Can somebody help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to alter your model `Items` but in order to know which item you must (add, remove) in/from your cart, each item must have a unique Id or similar

```
class Items{
  int id;
  // ...
}
```

Hence, your `ListView.builder` will look like this

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      // ...
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart,),
        onPressed: () {
          // Get the item id
          final itemId = itemList[index].id;
          // Then do your operations
        },
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I'm following this : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.  As your suggestion also in the same direction, let me try reorienting my class. I will come back here  and update. Thank you.

Comment: I added 'id' declared numbers and rendered the UI.I declared a List<Items>, which is empty, in the provider to add items to  List<Items> on add_to_cart. But it is throwing errors.                                                                                                                            
 The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Class 'List<Items>' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: call(Instance of 'Items').

Comment: I found there is something wrong with provider. I posted the contents of the provider below.Can you  help me..                  
 List<Items> cart_items=[];
    
  List<Items> get item => cart_items;
    get count => cart_items.length;

    get add => cart_items;
    Items getById(int id) => Items(id, cart_items[id].name,cart_items[id].picture,cart_items[id].quantity,cart_items[id].price);

    set add(item){
     if(cart_items.contains(item.id)==false){
       cart_items.add(Items(item.id, item.name, item.picture, item.quantity, item.price));
        notifyListeners();
   }
 }

Comment: Will try to help you ASAP. Am bit busy

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle, i'm able to do what I wanted. A brief explanation can help others.

Here we go:

1. Render your UI from Model data.
2. Use providers and apply at appropriate level. I declared a 'List of Items class' and  add/delete
   methods to perform operations on the List. With help of
   ListView,identified the index and added that item to the List
   of the provider class.
3. Cart UI can be rendered from the List of the provider class.

My explanation helps in understanding theoretically first because there is so much of practical code available. This is easily doable provided what is needed and what is available in the flutter are clear.